# UI-Router hook for after Template fetched and attached to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have to support a legacy module that needs to run synchronous code after templates have been fetched and attached to the dom.

We are migrating from a custom router to [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/index.html). The route is resolved successfully and the templates are fetched correctly.  However I cannot seem to find a transition that allows me to hook after the templates are loaded.

Details:

- UI-Router: 1.0.0-rc.1
- Angular: 1.5.8

I have tried the `onSuccess` [hook](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onsuccess) returning a resolved `promise` chained with a `then` callback.  This is still within the transition lifecycle however and the templates have not been attached/inserted into the dom. The same can be said for using resolve blocks in the state definition.

Performing a timeout after `onSuccess`.  This clearly works but is not the solution.

We do have [redux-ui-router](https://github.com/neilff/redux-ui-router) so I can dispatch a thunk when `onSuccess` is called but that would require extra refactoring for the older module.

Any information or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with `onSuccess`.  The `onSuccess` hook is invoked *in response to a successful state-machine transition*.  [UI-Router itself synchronizes the views *using an `onSuccess` hook*](https://github.com/ui-router/core/blob/1f2f74a11fe7286b234cc59def0b480a75ee7649/src/hooks/views.ts#L29-L53) using the default priority of `0`.  When the views are synchronized, the templates are compiled and added into the DOM.

By registering an `onSuccess` hook with a slightly lower priority, your hook will be invoked after the view synchronizing hook completes.

```
app.run(function($transitions) {
  $transitions.onSuccess({}, yourhook, { priority: -1 } )
});
```

Note that AngularJS template rendering *is inherently asynchronous* because of the digest loop.

---

Here is a plunker that demonstrates both points:

- the hooks have a `debugger` before and after the views are synchronized
- the template variable interpolation is not completed until the digest cycle is complete

http://plnkr.co/edit/OpKexobSQ6WTrP87k4Tb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Chris T answer is a better solution to a single template fetch but we had to fetch multiple.  We ended up leveraging the resolve block.

```
resolve: {
            templates: ['$q', '$templateRequest', function ($q, $templateRequest) {
                    return $q.all([
                        $templateRequest('../template1.html'),
                        $templateRequest('../template.html')
                    ]);
                }]
        },
```

and then init on success in the promise resolution.